# ip_conntrack_max test not working

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, packet

I am trying to do some `ip_conntrack_max` kernel parameter testing, but somehow its not working.

`-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

I have set following value to see its filling connection or not.

```
echo "10" > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max
```

Now i am creating many connection using `nc` command

```
# nc -z -n -u -v 192.168.1.100 12000-32000
```

I can see its filling `ip_conntrack` tables but not dropping any connection. I can ssh on that machine even connection is full. am i doing something wrong?  or it has to be from different `src IP` address?

generally i should get following message in /var/log/messages, but i am not seeing anything like following. In short i am trying to re-produce following error.

```
ip_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
```

Comment: I think i found why it wasn't working, look like it only works with `ESTABLISHED` connection

Comment: You should post that as an answer, it will be much easier to find for other people with similar problems.  Also, rep ;)

Comment: here you go!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

ip_conntrack_max only observer `ESTABLISHED` connection, I was running UDP scanner which has no state.

Comment: I was trying to reproduce what you did above and the code in your question actually did work for me.  Maybe a timing problem (i.e. you tried connecting before the connection tracker was filled up)?

Comment: I tried many way but it didn't work, but when i use `TCP` it works immediately. i will give it a shot again